# Restful service in rails without scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest

I am working on Ruby on Rails 3.0.6. Is there a way to create Restful services in rails without the use of scaffold generation??

Ref : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cb08016/
      http://jarrettcolby.com/articles/3-rest-and-ruby-on-rails-the-big-picture/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Scaffolding generators are just a quick way to boot strap.  You don't have to use them at all.

You could script/generate model, then manually create your controller and views.

`rails g` will show you all the generators. `rails g resource` will explain the options for creating a resource.

Comment: Oh ok... so like how to create RESTful service in the same?